# JVM Settings for elasticsearch and fscrawler

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jvm, fscrawler

I am using elasticsearch and fscrawler for searching about 7TB of data.. The process starts well until it just stalls after sometime. It must be running out of memory, I am trying to add my heap using https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/jvm-settings.html but I keep getting the error invalid maximum heap size.

[image]

Is that the right way of setting up the heap? What am I missing?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have 40GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the 32 bit version of Java. If that's the case, you need to install the 64 bit JVM and make sure to update your JAVA_HOME to reflect the new version.

More detailed info can be found [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/invalid-initial-and-maximum-heap-size.html).

Comment: Well I believe its 64 bit.

Comment: What do you get when running java -version ?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)